# When set left margin in FPDF ( python 3.8 )?

Tags: pdf-generation, fpdf, python-3.8, margins

I cannot find any information in google ( score of search was to old php-ers websites ) only thing what i find is a poor documentation https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/set_left_margin/index.html for this method

I know i should set_left_margin this before i have created first page but ...

####1 first place one use - python give communicate

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zlecenieWykonaniaBadania.py", line 78, in <module>
    main()
  File "zlecenieWykonaniaBadania.py", line 64, in main
    pdf.set_left_margin(4.0)
 ##venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fpdf/fpdf.py", line 263, in set_left_margin
    if self.page > 0 and self.x < margin:
AttributeError: 'PDF' object has no attribute 'page'
```

on ##############2 give me

```
  File "zlecenieWykonaniaBadania.py", line 77, in <module>
    main()
  File "zlecenieWykonaniaBadania.py", line 66, in main
    pdf.set_left_margin(4.0) 
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fpdf/fpdf.py", line 263, in set_left_margin
    if self.page > 0 and self.x < margin:
AttributeError: 'PDF' object has no attribute 'page'
```

on ##############3 give me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zlecenieWykonaniaBadania.py", line 77, in <module>
    main()
  File "zlecenieWykonaniaBadania.py", line 67, in main
    pdf.add_page()
/generatorPdfLims/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fpdf/fpdf.py", line 358, in add_page
    if self.state == DocumentState.CLOSED:
AttributeError: 'PDF' object has no attribute 'state'
```

When i could change ? Sorry for stupid question

```
import logging
import argparse
from fpdf import FPDF

class PDF(FPDF):

    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def header(self):
        zdjecie="rac.png"
        polozenieXzdj=8
        polozenieYzdj=8
        rozmiarZdjecia=33
        # Logo (zdjecie, polozenie x, polozenie y, rozmiar)
        self.image(zdjecie, polozenieXzdj, polozenieYzdj, rozmiarZdjecia)
        # Arial bold 15
        self.set_font('Arial', 'B', 12)
        # Move to the right
        self.cell(80)
        # Title
        self.cell(30, 10, 'Title', 1, 0, 'C')
        # Line break
        self.ln(20)

    # Page footer
    def footer(self):
        # Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
        self.set_y(-15)
        # Arial italic 8
        self.set_font('Arial', 'I', 8)
        # Page number
        self.cell(0, 10, 'Page ' + str(self.page_no()) + '/{nb}', 0, 0, 'C')

    #first page
    def firstPage(self):
        x=1000
        y=40

        self.ln(40)
        #self.set_left_margin(3)
        self.set_text_color(0,232,0)
        #cell(x,y, "tekst", wielkosc ramki(0 brak ramkii), nie wiem)
        self.cell(x, 0, 'ZLECENIE WYKONANIA BADANIA', 0, 1)
        self.ln(20)
        self.cell(x, 0, 'ZLECENIE WYKONANIA BADANIA', 0, 1)


def main():
    def_params()
    # Instantiation of inherited class
    pdf = PDF()
    #pdf.set_left_margin(4.0) #####1
    pdf.alias_nb_pages(str(2))
    #pdf.set_left_margin(4.0) #####2
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_left_margin(3.0)  #####3
    pdf.set_font('Times', '', 12)
    pdf.firstPage()
    #for i in range(1, 41):
    #    pdf.cell(0, 10, 'Printing line number ' + str(i), 0, 1)

    pdf.output('tuto2.pdf', 'F')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

ok i am only stupid

```
    # Instantiation of inherited class
     pdf = PDF()
     pdf.alias_nb_pages(str(2))
     pdf.add_page()
     pdf.set_font('Times', '', 12)
     pdf.set_left_margin(32)
     pdf.set_right_margin(32)
     pdf.firstPage()
```

code in this order of method, works

Please close question